# forgotpassword functionality without using springsecurity

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

In my grails(2.4.4 version) application,i am using mail plugin for sending confirmation mails, now  i need to implement code for forgot password.

can i achieve it without using spring security ?

with Thanks..

i did like in My **UserController**

```
def forgotPassword={
    if (params.email) {
        User user = User.findByEmail(params.email)
        if (user) {
            def password = randomService.generateRandomString(6)
            user.password = authenticateService.encodePassword(password)
            if (!user.save(flush:true)) {
                user.errors.each {
                    log.error "err $it"
                }
                flash.message = message(code: "UserController.msg.forgot.error")
            } else {
                UserService.sendmail {
                    to user.email
                    subject message(code:"UserController.mail.forgot.subject" )
                    body(view:"forgotPasswordEmail", model: [person:user, password:password])
                }
                flash.message = message(code:"UserController.msg.forgot", args:[user.email] )
            }
        } else {
            flash.message = message(code:"UserController.msg.forgot.unknown", args:[params.email])
        }
    }
}
```

its not showing any error but no result

Answer (score 0):

You should either:

1. have a view `/[yourController]/forgotPassword.gsp` to render your `flash.message`
2. render something to the output `render 'email was sent'` which would display this message only in browser
3. set status code of your response (for REST call) `response.status = 200`

Comment: describe your problem